# Is it possible to build a non-unitary quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

Is it possible to build a non-unitary circuit of quantum Boolean gates, apart from using measurement to achieve this?

Comment: Do you consider entangling with a qubit and then ignoring that qubit "measurement"?

Comment: (Related to DanielSank's comment, which appeared while I was writing this one:) If $A$ and $B$ are two quantum systems interacting with each other, then the time-evolution of $A$ itself is not unitary even though the time-evolution of the combined system is unitary. "Measurement" is (sort of) a special case of that. When you exclude measurement, are you excluding *all* interaction between the quantum computer and the rest of the world?

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circuit is non-unitary if and only if it implements a non-reversible transformation, that is, it involves loss of information. 
This can be due to measurements (i.e. interactions of the state with a larger environment), noise due to imperfections of the various components of the circuit, etc.

Note that ignoring some of the outputs of a circuit is equivalent to performing a measurement on them, and you can thus describe the corresponding evolution as non-unitary.

For example, the circuit $CNOT(H\otimes I)$ is unitary and operates as $|00\rangle\to|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ and $|10\rangle\to|00\rangle-|11\rangle$.
On the other hand, the corresponding transformation obtained by looking only at the action of this circuit on the first qubit, maps
$$
  |0\rangle\!\langle 0|\to
  \frac12(|0\rangle\!\langle0|+|1\rangle\!\langle1|) \equiv I/2, \\
  |1\rangle\!\langle 1|\to I/2.
$$
This is clearly a non-unitary transformation, as two orthogonal states are mapped to the same output.